# How to write OR rules/conditions in Firebase Remote Configurations?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-remote-config

We are using Firebase Remote Config as our remote configurations for our app. The issue is Android is using user attribute, `creationDate` while iOS is using `registrationDate`, Now we want to add common configuration for both platforms.

So I though maybe we can use `OR` condition

[image: Conition we want to use]

Is it possible? I tried clicking on "and" and searching, could not found anything related!

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no logical or for Remote Config.  As you can see from the [conditional expression reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/condition-reference) for its REST API, there is only logical and.